# Is this possible in Dart to define similar declaration `GroupByIterator<TSource, Grouping<TKey, TElement>>`

Tags: dart

I cannot declare class in this manner. May be I am wrong. Is this possible in other way?

```dart
class GroupByIterator<TSource, Grouping<TKey, TElement>> {
}

class Grouping<TKey, TElement> {
}
```

I got a dozen compiler errors on this declaration.

Please, help me define similar declaration.

P.S.

I know the following way, but I want to know that it can be made easier?..

```dart
void main() {
  var it1 = new GroupByIterator<List, Grouping<int, String>, int, String>();
}

class GroupByIterator<TSource, TResult extends Grouping<TKey, TElement>, TKey, TElement> {
  GroupByIterator() {
    print('GroupByIterator');
  }
}

class Grouping<TKey, TElement> {
}
```

I want simialr to this.

```dart
var it1 = new GroupByIterator<List, Grouping<int, String>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
class GroupByIterator<TSource, TResult, TKey, TElement, T extends Grouping<TKey, TElement>> implements Iterator<TResult> {
  GroupByIterator() {
    print('GroupByIterator');
  }
}
```

It seems that you must list all Type parameters in the 'top' level to use it in the following 'lower' levels.

Comment: Thanks, but I know this way. It is not very convenient way and I cannot find a reasonable explanation for it. Why I should list the parameters twice?

Comment: You could have added to your question that you already know a way but looking for a more concise way.